# using contents within a Django Zip File

Tags: python, django, download, zip

I was sent a Django Project from a friend and want to start working on it. I'm mostly a JS developer but was wondering if there was an npm i equivalent for django that will download everything I need?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if you have in folder file called **requirements.txt**

you can use this command in cmd or terminal where this file exists

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```